# Why do my headphones stop working on my LG Android?

Tags: hardware, music, headphones, lg

About yesterday, my headphones randomly started pausing my music. At first, I thought it was my headphones which are Apple iPod/iPhone 5 headphones that I've had for a few months from an old iPhone, so I tried another pair that are brand new and only used once or twice and the same thing happened. It would pause the music and it didn't show the headphone icon at the top like it should on both pairs. And then when I'd go to my music player to start up the song, it would play the music through my phone speakers when the headphones were plugged in. Why?

Comment: This can also happen for a simple reason of your head phone  port clogged with lint or some muck. Try cleaning with a soft cloth inserted with help of  tooth pick and turn your phone upside down gently tapping to dislodge dirt

Answer (score 2):

After THREE YEARS of searching for a fix... I think I just found a solution - and felt obligated to spread the information. Just plug the headphones in slowly... That's actually all there was to it... The notification icon for a plugged in audio jack at the top of the screen will show up differently if you did it right.

This reddit post: https://www.google.com/amp/s/amp.reddit.com/r/LGG3/comments/2siwyp/is_there_a_rom_or_fix_that_makes_g3_detect_all/  the user RandomGenera7ed  tells us to plug the jack into the headphone plug slowly - causing it to show up as a three prong headphone jack and not a four prong jack (four prong jacks have a mike wire that can have pause/skip/volume-change/GOOGLE VOICE functionality while three prong audio jacks do not).  Apparently plugging a three prong jack in too quickly confuses the phone into thinking it has a four prong jack plugged in.

Comment: Damn, this actually worked.  My headphones didn't work any all 4 family phones but did on my laptop, so I knew they weren't broken.  Plugged them in slowly and it all works.  Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

I think your phone audio card might be broken. Do the phone speaker / Bluetooth speaker work? In that case, I would send your phone back to LG.

Answer (score 0):

If the headphones were working previously on the phone and now they just suddenly stopped working, then it's likely that the phone's audio hardware has malfunctioned.

Alternatively, there is also a small possibility that some drivers have been updated on your phone to detect Apple headphones and not allow them to be used. (This is a conspiracy theory, but Apple does do this with their Lightning connector such that if you buy a counterfeit one or buy from some other vendor it won't work).

Have you tried a totally different set of headphones (not Apple ones) on this phone?

Does the headphone jack fit totally/properly in the port? Sometimes a little fidgeting with it and pressing a little harder gets some of the grooves to click into place so that the right connections are flush against each other. (Had this issue on a Nexus 7 with Apple Earpods)

Personally i've tested Apple Earpods (iPhone 5 headphones) on a Google Nexus 4 and 5 (both LG devices) and they work. However on a Samsung Galaxy Ace the same set of headphones behaved quite similar to what you described. They worked initially, but then started doing weird things with playing and pausing music, and not showing up in the notifications. Also the mic didn't work for me. It causes some loud ringing noise on the other end.when you're on hands-free with the headphones.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me too! What I did was put my phone into reverse portrait mode. If that does not work then unplug the battery. If it still  does not work then find an earbud, remove all the cotton around its head and move it around in the headphone socket.

Comment: Hi! I couldn't make complete sense out of your answer but I tried to make it clean. Please feel free to roll back or edit the answer if I messed up somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Reply date 12/04/17

Hi to everyone who is having the mic problem on lg g3 where the you can hear the pesrson you have called wearing headphones but they can not hear you, the way to fix this problem is to use the original lg g3 headphones as this phone doesn't work with other headphones like samsung and other brands.